# Which approach is better in terms of database performance - one table group by operations or multiple tables serializable transaction?

Tags: sql, database-design, architecture, database-performance

I'm developing a reservation system based on an SQL database (no limitations on the specific DB).

**Schema:**
[image]

**Workflow:**
[image]

Now I'm using a special 'actual_reservations' view based on a cusom group-by with filtration logic to identify actually placed reservations like:

```html
CREATE VIEW `reserv-io`.`actual_reserved_resources` AS
  SELECT
    `r`.`id`,
    `a`.`resource_id`,
    `a`.`type_id`,
    `a`.`status_id`,
    `a`.`reservation_start`,
    `a`.`reservation_end`
  FROM `reserv-io`.`actions` `a`
    JOIN (SELECT
            `r`.`id`      `id`,
            MAX(`a`.`id`) `action_id`
          FROM `reserv-io`.`reservations` `r`
            JOIN `reserv-io`.`actions` `a` ON `r`.`id` = `a`.`reservation_id`
          WHERE (`r`.`id` NOT IN
                 (SELECT `r`.`id` `id`
                  FROM `reserv-io`.`reservations` `r`
                    JOIN `reserv-io`.`actions` `a` ON `r`.`id` = `a`.`reservation_id`
                  WHERE (`a`.`status_id` IN
                         (SELECT `id`
                          FROM `reserv-io`.`reservation_statuses`
                          WHERE `name` = 'Canceled')))
                 AND `a`.`status_id` IN
                     (SELECT `id`
                      FROM `reserv-io`.`reservation_statuses`
                      WHERE `name` = 'Approved' OR `name` = 'Accepted'))
          GROUP BY `r`.`id`) `b`
      ON `a`.`id` = `b`.`action_id`
    JOIN `reserv-io`.`reservations` `r` ON `r`.`id` = `a`.`reservation_id`;
```

And to determine whether there are any overlapping with other reservations with procedure like this:

```html
CREATE PROCEDURE HAS_OVERLAPPING_RESERVATION_WITH_TYPE_SELF_CHECK(
  IN  RESERVATION      BIGINT,
  IN  RESOURCE         INT,
  IN  RESERVATION_TYPE INT,
  IN  STARTS_AT        DATETIME,
  IN  ENDS_AT          DATETIME,
  OUT RESULT           BIT)
  BEGIN
    SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM actual_reserved_resources r
        WHERE r.resource_id = RESOURCE
              AND r.type_id = RESERVATION_TYPE
              AND r.reservation_start < ENDS_AT
              AND r.reservation_end > STARTS_AT
              AND r.id <> RESERVATION)
      THEN TRUE
           ELSE FALSE END
    INTO RESULT;
  END$$
```

I already have good indexes on the 'actions' table, but I'm not sure that my approach with single table for all actions related to the reservation is really scalable. I've heard about approach where I store all pending and actually approved reservations into separate tables, and synchronize them manually into transaction.

My question is about which approach from your POV is better in terms of database performance, scalability and good data design?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that:

- Do not take anyone's answer here for granted; instead, benchmark with real-world data, to measure actual performance.
- Whatever the answer is, it will not really matter as much as you fear. It will certainly not make the difference between a scalable system and a non-scalable one.
- If it turns out that there is in fact any merit in some kind of segregation of records into pending and approved, you will be able to achieve it with *row partitioning* (look it up) so you can keep everything in one logical table and avoid messing up your schema in the name of performance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the size of your dataset or the size of the system on which you're running your queries. Until you get large datasets it probably doesn't make much difference. My personal experience with large datasets is that joins across more than two tables can perform very slowly as the system starts to swap out to disk instead of keeping things in memory. On Oracle years ago, I had a particular query that needed to touch six tables. In one query, it took ~six hours to run. As individual queries touching two tables at a time, it took 15 minutes. I had a different query on MySQL which touched some number of tables. Breaking it down to smaller queries lowered the total run time from around seven hours to seven minutes.

Comment: Okay, I should have specified it during posting this question.
Size of data - up to 10000 users, up to 1000 reservations per year with approx. 5 actions gives us 50 millions of records per year